# How to send some even before Telegram webapp close?

Tags: telegram-bot

[when click cross it show dialog to confirm, then if user click confirm I want to send some event or message to bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgxC9.png)
Hello, Sorry for my English and I hope you understand what I mean.
I try to find out how to handle some events before Telegram web app close but not see.